# Fault detected on drive 1 in disk drive bay 1 on a Dell R620, but is it really a concern?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, dell

It gives me this code on the display from the server (Fault detected on drive 1 in disk drive bay 1) , but in iDRAC:

Storage summary:
[image: Storage summary.]

Fault logs:
[image: fault logs.]

Disks online:
[image: Disks online.]

I really don’t know what is happening, it’s a RAID 1, 2 SSD/1TB. Should I worry?

And the disk is blinking orange so I guess it's not a good sign? It’s weird because the SSDs are brand new, and the RAID is like 2 months old.

Comment: Its giving a fault every 4 minutes, including one line for power issue.  Why do you think its okay?

Comment: @RohitGupta the power thing, is because i unplugged one of the PSU by accident, and the disk drive error only happens when i reboot the server, and i dont think its ok, thats why i asked

Comment: Can you run a S.M.A.R.T test on the disk in question.   It is definitely reasonable to be concerned.

Comment: Also, what model server, and is it in a climate controlled environment?    Not the same interface - but I occasionally get S.M.A.R.T warnings on one of my SSDs which is not in a controlled environment which is tripping because the temperature gets a bit hot for it and then reports fine after a little while.  Its been like that for months and I'm not at all worried about it.

Comment: @davidgo ok, dumb question -- how do i run a S.M.A.R.T test? can i do it in iDRAC? and the server is in a environment thats very cold

Comment: No idea how to do it from in that Interface (if its even possible) and doing it in the OS depends on the RAID controller and OS.     If you use Windows https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/ is a common go-to program.  Under Linux there is a utility "smartmontools" or "smartmonutils" or similar which has the "smartctl"  command which can query disks - but the parameters may vary depending on the controller.

Comment: @davidgo i tried Smartmontools because i run Ubuntu Server, but unfortunately "device lacks SMART capability"

Comment: What RAID/Disk controller do you have?

Comment: @davidgo PERC H710

Comment: Have a read of https://serverfault.com/questions/589070 - I expect the smartctl commands will work and it also has otjer hints - albeit for Redhat.

Comment: @davidgo so, i did : `omreport storage pdisk controller=0 vdisk=0` and every SSD Status is "Non-Critical", here is some more info just in case i dont know what im looking at https://justpaste.it/akjo8

Comment: I hypothesise the Failure Predicted               : No is picking up the SMART summary and the disk is OK.  Getting the SMART results would still be valuable.

Comment: So if the SSDs are fine, why the bloody error? weird, im gonna try to get the SMART thing working on Ubuntu, thank you, you've been helping me ALOT